# JQuery working on jsfiddle but not on my server

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsfiddle

I have this simple script that validates some inputs and shows error messages.
Here is my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2kJVU/

DOM is loaded, script embedded. The code is working partially but the e-mail message is always showing on my website, even if the Email field is filled out correctly.
This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#registreren').click(function(){  
        var Email = $('#Email').val();
        var Postcode =$('#Postcode').val();

        $("#add_err2").html("");

        if(Email == "") {
            $("#add_err2").css({"border-radius":"5px", "background":"#fd7777", "border":"1px solid #ff0000"});
            $("#add_err2").html("Vul a.u.b. een E-mail adres in <br>");
        }
        else if(!validateEmail(Email)){
            //$("#add_err2").css({"border-radius":"5px", "background":"#ff4e4e", "border":"1px solid #ff0000"});
            $("#add_err2").append("Vul a.u.b. een geldig E-mail adres in <br>");
        }

        if(Postcode == "") {
            //$("#add_err2").css({"border-radius":"5px", "background":"#ff4e4e", "border":"1px solid #ff0000"});
            $("#add_err2").append("Vul a.u.b. een Postcode in <br>");
        }
        else if(Postcode.length < 4){
            //$("#add_err2").css({"border-radius":"5px", "background":"ff4e4e", "border":"1px solid #ff0000"});
            $("#add_err2").append("Vul a.u.b. een geldige Postcode in <br>");
        } else {
            // send backend service;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./postcodecheck.php",
                data: "registreren=true&Email="+Email+"&Postcode="+Postcode,
                success: function(html){    
                    if(html=='true')    {
                        $("#add_err2").hide();
                        window.location="./registreren.php";
                    }
                    else    {
                        $("#add_err2").css({"border-radius":"5px", "background":"#496999", "border":"1px solid #174385", "width":"350px;", "color":"#ffffff"});
                        $("#add_err2").html("Helaas is BoxCloud nog niet beschikbaar in uw regio. Als u op de hoogte wilt blijven van nieuwe regio’s, meld u dan a.u.b. via de onderstaande balk aan voor de nieuwsbrief van BoxCloud");
                    }
                },
            });
            function validateEmail(email) {
                var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email);
            }
            return false;
        };
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="klant_worden" action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="Email" type="email" name="Email" class="inputs" placeholder="Uw e-mail adres">
        <input id="Postcode" type="text" name="Postcode" class="inputs" placeholder="Uw postcode (1234AB)">
        <!-- <input type="submit" class="submitclient" id="registreren" value="Registreren" name="registreren" onclick="validateForm();"> -->
        <input type="button" class="submitclient" id="registreren" value="Registreren" name="registreren">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<section class="err" id="add_err2"><br></section>
```

This is working fine there but not on my server. Why?

EDIT:

Live version can be found here(first signup box): 
http://www.boxcloud.nl/site/

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Your 'email message' is fired in the conditional evaluation of an ajax response. This means that your PHP script is performing the return of the data, which is where the hiccup lay. It has nothing to do with your jQuery. And since this is related to Email, I can only assume you're using the `mail` function. but there's no possible way for us to answer this question without seeing that code and the mail log.

Comment: also validate email is not defined

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon No errors in the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate email should be outside the else loop: http://jsfiddle.net/2kJVU/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registreren').click(function () {
        var Email = $('#Email').val();
        var Postcode = $('#Postcode').val();

        $("#add_err2").html("");

        if (Email === "") {
            $("#add_err2").css({
                "border-radius": "5px",
                    "background": "#fd7777",
                    "border": "1px solid #ff0000"
            });
            $("#add_err2").html("Vul a.u.b. een E-mail adres in <br>");
        } else if (!validateEmail(Email)) {

            $("#add_err2").append("Vul a.u.b. een geldig E-mail adres in <br>");
        }

        if (Postcode === "") {
            $("#add_err2").append("Vul a.u.b. een Postcode in <br>");
        } else if (Postcode.length < 4) {
            $("#add_err2").append("Vul a.u.b. een geldige Postcode in <br>");
        } else {
            // send backend service;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./postcodecheck.php",
                data: "registreren=true&Email=" + Email + "&Postcode=" + Postcode,
                success: function (html) {
                    if (html == 'true') {
                        $("#add_err2").hide();
                        window.location = "./registreren.php";
                    } else {
                        $("#add_err2").css({
                            "border-radius": "5px",
                                "background": "#496999",
                                "border": "1px solid #174385",
                                "width": "350px;",
                                "color": "#ffffff"
                        });
                        $("#add_err2").html("Helaas is BoxCloud nog niet beschikbaar in uw regio. Als u op de hoogte wilt blijven van nieuwe regio’s, meld u dan a.u.b. via de onderstaande balk aan voor de nieuwsbrief van BoxCloud");
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });

    function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }


});
```